# Texture mapping from 3 view based images

Tags: python, matplotlib, vtk, texture-mapping, mayavi

I have 3d model with unwrapped UV and I have 3 images taken from 3 different angles in an equal light source.

[the images is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNty9.jpg)

I only want to stitch images to each other and the result should be like above.
the stitching of the issue caused by overlapping borders of images is not important I can handle that later.

the question is do I need to reconstruct the 3d Surface geometry for stitching images?

in this topic, they mentioned this but not explained well the process.
[[Vtk inserts incorrect color between nodes when mapping texture to mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137374/vtk-inserts-incorrect-color-between-nodes-when-mapping-texture-to-mesh])

if I sum how to combine 3-view based images to create texture?

thank you so much in advance